# NodeJS process posted file and return file

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I've been playing with NodeJS, and what I am trying to do is receive a file that the client sends, process the file (without saving it, requires a line by line process) and then send the result of the process as a file download.

So I have the following route:

```
app.post('/processFile', function(req, res) {
        var file = req.files.file;

        //Process file inline
        process.processFile(file, req).then((data) => {
            //res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=tokenized.txt');
            res.write(data, 'binary');
            res.end();
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(err);
        });

    });
```

The processFile function looks like this:

```
processFile: function(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
            input: fs.ReadStream(file)
        });

        var output = "";
        lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
            // Tokenize each line
            DoSomethingFunction(line).then((data) => {
                output += data + "\n";
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(`Error in line [${line}].`);
            });
        });

        resolve(output);
    });    
}
```

When I test it, it does nothing. I just get an empty response, I did some tests and noticed that the route is getting a reject() from the processFile() promise, but it has no message. After some more tests I noticed that:

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
   input: fs.ReadStream(file)
});
```

is not working, and it's the one sending the "reject".

Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `lineReader` is using an asynchronous event to gather its information.

Basically, this means that you're calling `resolve(output)` before the line reader has processed any data. Instead, you'll need to listen for another event: [the 'close' event](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close). This signifies that the line reader is done.

```
lineReader.on('close', () => {
  resolve(output);
});
```

There's one caveat though. Your `DoSomethingFunction` appears to also be asynchronous. That means that it's possible for it to be waiting to do some work when the 'close' event runs. One way of handling this would be to save the most recent result of `DoSomethingFunction` and attaching to that in the 'close' event.

```
// Initialize to a resolved promise just in case you don't receive
// any data from the user
let doSomethingPromise = Promise.resolve();

lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
  doSomethingPromise = DoSomethingFunction(line)
    .then((data) => {
      output += data + '\n';
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(`Error in line [${line}].`);
    });
});

lineReader.on('close', () => {
  // Wait for the DoSomethingFunction to finish
  doSomethingPromise.then(() => resolve(output));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am now getting an error on the readline: TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer.

Comment: @FedeE. That's kind of a different error. It's likely related to what the value of `file` is and possible the fact that you're using `fs.ReadStream` instead of `new fs.ReadStream` or `fs.createReadStream`.

Comment: yeah... I managed to fix that... yet I can't manage to wait for the whole process to complete in order to "emmit" the resolve()

Comment: @FedeE. Did you see what I did with saving the promise from `DoSomethingFunction`? That should make it work correctly

Comment: Yeah, however, I had to create an array in the line event, and then fire the line by line processing upon receiving the close event, as I needed to maintain the order on the output. But your answer did help to understand how that worked. Thanks.